# Salesforce sandbox slow

Tags: sandbox, developer, salesforce-support

I am an IT Support person where I have salesforce sandbox environment. I used to check internet connection but every things is stable no ping break so far. Every thing like Zoho, Jira, Slack seems works perfect but often entire dev and specially my QA team say that internet is slow but when I check it, it seems working fine with full bandwidth. Even I am not able to ping or check trace route on sandbox instance may be it is due to security reasons. I am very frustrate with this situation. I have two ISP with fiber connection of 100mbs with 50 mbs connection with firewall for blocking sites and applications. around 25 people in dev and QA team. Other teams like social media and marketing team rare tells me about slow internet complain. Please help me in this regards.

Answer (score 1):

First, have a user with the complaint try running a speed test at https://test.salesforce.com/speedtest.jsp. They will need to log in, and this will capture their values from the specific Sandbox instance. Compare this to your own results. Also, find out how much memory they have, what browser they are using, etc. Salesforce is usually pretty fast in general, so slowdowns tend to be local. If you and they both have abnormally high pings or low download speeds, and so therefore the instance itself is suspect, contact Technical Support. If it's just some tests that are bad, you'll have to troubleshoot that locally. Have them run an ISP speed test as well, just to rule out the possibility of local service issues. Also, check https://status.salesforce.com to see if the service is having problems.

Do all the standard procedures you can think of. Try having them use the Clear All Data command in their browser (e.g. Ctrl-Shift-Del or Cmd-Shift-Del) to clear their cache. You don't need to clear cookies or other site data. After that, have them restart their computer, or at least their browser; Chrome, for example, stays running in the background by default, so you need to use the system tray icon to close Chrome completely, or use Ctrl-Shift-Q or Cmd-Q, or the ⋮ / ≡ | Exit menu option.

Other possible problems might include BGP routing on the local network if you're running your own routers, poor WiFi connectivity, etc. These kinds of things can be exceptionally difficult to troubleshoot if you don't have the proper tools. In summary, though, start with two speed tests to rule out Salesforce. If Salesforce is the problem, contact Support. Otherwise, try clearing browser data, and if that fails, you'll have to troubleshoot the problem locally. Salesforce *does* respond to `ping` and trace routes (e.g. `tracert`). If you're not getting any response, that's a problem with the ISP network, not Salesforce (unless Salesforce is actually down).